# Two of my contacts are internally being mixed up

Tags: contacts, sms, lineageos, bugs

Recently I've stumbled upon a very weird and cumbersome bug. Android mistakes one of my contacts for another. As far as I know it happens to exactly one pair of contacts on my phone (let's call them A and B). When trying to message A, it shows the proper message history, but the messages are sent to B >< This causes a lot of confusion for the recipients, and for me as well.

I've tried using a different messaging app (instead of the default one), but the end result is just the same.

Here's the bug captured on video:

https://vimeo.com/261324755

And in screenshot form:

1. I enter the name of contact A (starting with "Lucyna")

[image: I enter the name of contact A (starting with "Lucyna")]

2. I select the proper suggestion and I can see the message history with A:

[image: I select the proper suggestion and I can see the message history with A]

3. I tap the message field, and the moment it gains focus the name of the contact in the top bar changes to contact B!

[image: I tap the message field, and the moment it gains focus the name of the contact in the top bar changes to contact B!]

Sending the message now causes it to go to the wrong person.

The two contacts aren't related in any way, and I have no idea why did those two in particular get mixed.

I'm on Android 7.1.2

Comment: Interesting. They may not be connected in any way on your phone but maybe in Google contacts ( log in on PC and check ). What happens if you delete both contacts and create them afresh(after having backed up messages if they are important )

Comment: Is this stock android?  Also try the new default SMS app Android Messenger.  I believe the one you are using is being phased out.

Comment: I don't have GAPPS on my device, so it's not Google Contacts... Will try deleting and re-creating the contacts.  I'm using Lineage OS. How can I try the default new Android Messager?

Comment: Interesting. A not so useful question here .Do these nos. are identical  like A.1234567890 and B.4321567890.My miui nougat never picked similar nos however i named them and i had to type the dissimilar digits. :(

Comment: No, these numbers are quite different...

Comment: What's your question? If you've found a bug, you should report it to the ROM developer.

Answer (score 2):

Removing BOTH contacts and recreating them resolved the issue.

Comment: no. it does not resolve it. im stuck with the same thing. nothing worked